# Python pandas: filter out non-matching pairs from two different dataframes

Tags: pandas, filtering, data-science

I have two data frames as follows:

```
1. dataframe_1

           id  joinKey
0  a000jz4hqo  [clickart, 950, 000]
1  a0006zf55o  [ca, international, arcserve, lap, desktop]
2  a00004tkvy  [noah, activity, centre, jewel, case]
3  a000g80lqo  [white, newest]
4  a0006se5bq  [singing, coach, carry, a, tune]

2. dataframe_2

           id  joinKey
0  b000jz4hqo  [clickart, 950, 000]
1  b0006zf55o  [ca, international, arcserve, lap, desktop]
2  b00004tkvy  [noah, s, ark, activity, centre, jewel, case]
3  b000g80lqo  [peachtree, jewel]
4  b0006se5bq  [singing, coach, unlimited, carry, a, tune]
```

I want to filter out non-matching pairs so as to prepare a data frame having data of dataframe_1 and dataframe_2 to carry out further data analysis.

To avoid n*n comparisons, I am flattening the dataframe_1 and dataframe_2 using pandas.DataFrame.explode.

I get new data frames as follows:

```
new_df1:

         id   joinKey
0  a000jz4hqo  clickart
0  a000jz4hqo       950
0  a000jz4hqo       000
0  a0006zf55o  ca
0  a0006zf55o  international

new_df2:

         id   joinKey
0  b000jz4hqo  clickart
0  b000jz4hqo       950
0  b000jz4hqo       000
0  b0006zf55o  ca
0  b0006zf55o  international
```

As I understood, The SQL query to filter the data is as follows:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM `new_df1 ` a,`new_df2 ` b
WHERE a.joinkey = b.joinkey AND a.id < b.id;
```

My questions:

1. What is the equivalent syntax in pandas dataframe for the above SQL syntax so as to filter out the non- matching pairs?
2. Is there any better approach to filter out non-matching pairs?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: @thushv89 Thank you for your help. I did use pd.DataFrame.merge  to merge both the data frames based on column name -"joinkey" and then dropped the duplicates. But it took me two steps to do this. Is it achievable with a single step as we see in the SQL syntax that I have put up in the description?